# Determine which tab select in tabbarcontroller

Tags: ios, ios7, uitabbarcontroller, appdelegate

I've implemented the following in my app delegate and attempted to check the selected index.  What I've found though is this value is the tab that it's on when a new tab is clicked, not the new tab.  Is there a way to find which tab was selected?

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    int *i = tabBarController.selectedIndex;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If I am not mistaken, you can get the index of the selected tab with

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
    NSUInteger selectedIndex = [tabBarController.viewControllers indexOfObject:viewController];
    // ...
    return YES or NO;
}
```

Comment: The problem is the code is in the wrong delegate method, called before the tab is actually changed.

Comment: @rmaddy: You might be right, but `shouldSelectViewController` is usually implemented if you want to  *decide* wether the new tab should be selected or not. In `didSelectViewController`, it is too late for that.

Comment: It seems the OP wants the new index. Your code to check the index of the newly selected VC will give that answer. But if the user just wants to know the new index after the fact, then my answer seems more direct. If there is a need to validate the selection, then of course your answer is better.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the `tabBarController:didSelectViewController:` delegate method. That is called after the tab is selected.

And your `int *i` should actually be `int i` or better yet, `NSUInteger i`.

Answer (score 0):

Swift version:

```
func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelectViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
    var shouldSelect = true
    if let viewControllers = tabBarController.viewControllers where viewControllers.indexOf(viewController) == lastIndex {
        shouldSelect = false
    }
    return shouldSelect
}
```